# ssh problem at CentOS 5.6

Tags: ssh, centos5

After installing CentOS, when I try to remote connect via ssh it show an error like this.
How can I resolve this?

```
Siam-Wannakosits-MacBook-Pro:~ragopor$ ssh root@192.168.1.10
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY! 
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now
(man-in-the-middle attack)! It is also possible that the 
RSA host key has just been changed. The fingerprint for
the RSA key sent by the remote host is
b8:23:20:f7:d5:7c:1f:5f:f5:9c:ee:46:67:19:58:68.
Please contact your system administrator. Add correct host 
key in /Users/ragopor/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this 
message. Offending key in /Users/ragopor/.ssh/known_hosts:5 
RSA host key for 192.168.1.10 has changed and you have 
requested strict checking. Host key verification failed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `/Users/ragopor/.ssh/known_hosts`on your local computer (Macbook Pro) and delete the **fifth** line, save it and try again.

Or, if you want to have something you can put in the terminal:

```
sudo awk 'NR!=5' /Users/ragopor/.ssh/known_hosts > /Users/ragopor/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Another one-liner, just in case: `sed -i 5d Users/ragopor/.ssh/known_hosts`.